# Cannot use wp_signon()

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try this code

```
$creds = array( 'user_login' =>  $_POST['benutzername'], 'user_password' => $_POST['passwort'], 'remember' => true );
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) ): echo $user->get_error_message(); endif;
wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
return $user;
```

I get this message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/formatting.php:4179)
>   in /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 925 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/formatting.php:4179)
>   in /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 926 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/formatting.php:4179)
>   in /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 927 Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_User could not
>   be converted to string in
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/your-click.ch/httpdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php
>   on line 286

I am using that code in shortcode.php. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the WP Manual for the [`wp_signon`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon#Notes) function:

> This function sends headers to the page. It must be run before any
>   content is returned.

According to the error you get, it seems that you're using this function after some content has being returned already.

Further more, it seems that WP team advise to use that function in the hook `after_setup_theme` which:

> will make it run before the headers and cookies are sent, so it can
>   set the needed cookie for login.